# Generic sums in Mathematica

Tags: summation

I would like to treat sums in very generic manners, but it looks like mathematica is very bad at that. For example, it cannot simplify to zero such expressions :

```
Sum[y[i], {i, 1, dim}] - Sum[y[j], {j, 1, dim}] // Simplify
Sum[a y[i], {i, 1, dim}] - a Sum[y[i], {i, 1, dim}] // Simplify
```

Is there a package which implements at least the three properties below for the sum ?
$$ \mathrm{Independent \ of \ indices \ : \ } \sum_i x_i = \sum_j x_j $$
$$ \mathrm{Linear : \ } \sum_i \lambda x_i = \lambda \sum_i x_i $$
$$ \mathrm{Simplifying \ Kroenecker \ deltas : \ } \sum_{i,j} \delta_{i,j} x_i x_j = \sum_i x_i^2 $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [Simplifying expressions involving Sum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31135/simplifying-expressions-involving-sum). Also: [How can I get simplified answer for SUM?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273780/how-can-i-get-simplified-answer-for-sum)

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262425/how-to-integrate-a-symbolic-sum